# Term that implies design and engineering

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I want know if the English language has a term that means "design and engineering".

Comment: can you replace *implies* with a different word? It's a little difficult to imagine what you mean by this.

Comment: This question is better asked on an Engineering Q&A.

Comment: Ok, I'm referring to "means"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are be referring to **tech-design** or [design technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_technology)  meaning:

'**the study, design, development, application, implementation, support and management of computer and non-computer based technologies** *for the express purpose of communicating, using various mediums, product design intent and constructability as well as to facilitate product operation and maintenance and to ultimately improve overall product design realization, construction, operation and maintenance.'*

Comment: Please re-read the Wiki entry -- 'design technology' is not the same as 'design & engineering.'